# Can't 'cd' with PHP shell_exec()

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm trying to write a script to browse and return similar to working in the terminal.

Most commands work fine, however `cd /path/to/files` just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Paste some code, please.  This description is not sufficient to determine what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each command to `shell_exec` runs in its own shell. Thus, if you do a `cd`, that will only affect that command.

If you want to change directory, use [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php). It is a PHP function.

`shel_exec('cd /some/where');` actually works *just fine* (it changes the *current* `shell_exec` to a different directory), but it will not hold on to the current directory after the `shell_exec` finishes. This means that the next command won't share the same state that would have been altered by the call to `cd`.

Answer (score 1):

What about PHP chdir?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

Or use backticks?

```
`cd /path/to/files`
```

Comment: AFAIK backticks execute the command using `shell_exec`, so backticks won't solve the problem.